# Featrue importance according to logistic regression. in python

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, python, feature-selection

I've trained a logistic regression over my data. I checked feature importance:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

features = X_train.columns
importance = Model.best_estimator_.coef_[0]

plt.bar(features, importance)
plt.title("Feature Importance according to logistic regression")
plt.ylabel("Improtance")
plt.show()
```

[image]

and the importance could be seen also here

```
Model.best_estimator_.coef_[0]

array([1.09365005e+00, 7.50386093e-01, 4.29639078e-04, 5.99721148e-01])
```

My question is what is the meaning of these results? what are those numbers?
I thought it was percentages before but 1.09365005e+00 means more than 100% importance, so it can't be percentages

Comment: Aren't these the estimated coefficients?  In what sense do you conceive of them as being "feature importance"?

Comment: These are estimated coefficients.

Comment: Because these are *coefficients*, their interpretation as *importance* is at best nuanced and at worst dubious, depending on who you ask & what your data represent. One source of caution is that the coefficients are expressed as units of the target per units of the independent variable, so comparing coefficients means comparing incomparable units of measurement. Re-expressing an IV in different units (eg. length in cm vs km) will likewise change the coefficient value. For more detail, see the "Race of Variables" section of Gary King, "How Not to Lie with Statistics" (1985).

Comment: More information in this search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logistic+regression+importance+answers%3A1+score%3A3 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interpret%20coefficient%20logistic%20answers%3a1